# Граф git состоит из одной ветки после ветвления и слияния

Tags: git

У меня есть ветки:

```
git branch -a

* develop
  master
  beta
```

после:

```
 git checkout -b develop
 git mеrge beta
```

но 
     git log --graph --decorate --oneline

не показывает ветки

```
* e798b65 (HEAD -> develop, beta)
* 16ea2cc
* 7a8e294 
* fc69adb (master)
* 8b1f562 
* a18bab9 
* a18bab9
* a18bab9
* a18bab9
```

Почему так? Насколько это критично?

Answer (score 0):

Это из-за того, что по умолчанию git делает слияние методом fast-forward. Добавьте ключ --no-ff и вы увидите коммит слияния.

```
git mеrge beta --no-ff
```

Можно исправить поведение по умолчанию следующим образом:

```
git config --global merge.ff false
```

Comment: В моем случает даже после ветвления не видно веток. Почему так?

Comment: В git ветка - это просто указатель на коммит. Поэтому сразу после создания метки и нескольких коммитов в ней вы увидите одну линию в графе. Только после слияния методом --no-ff вы увидите то, что ожидаете.